# Rename multiple images within folders using text files

Tags: python, filenames, batch-rename

I'm trying to practice python with file rename.
Rename a multiple of images within folders, each folder contains a multiple of images,
each folder with a specific number, using text files, each text file with a folder number:

before

```
Multi Folder Images
│
│
├── E01
│   ├── 0001.png
│   ├── 0002.png
│   ├── 0003.png
│   ├── 0004.png
│   └── 0005.png
│     
├── E02
│   ├── 0001.png
│   ├── 0002.png
│   ├── 0003.png
│   ├── 0004.png
│   └── 0005.png
│ 
│  
├── E03
│   ├── 0001.png
│   ├── 0002.png
│   ├── 0003.png
│   ├── 0004.png
│   └── 0005.png

Multi Folder text

│
│
├── E01.txt   "inside text"
│   ├── 0_00_01_713__0_00_05_081_01
│   ├── 0_00_05_093__0_00_08_916_02
│   ├── 0_00_08_926__0_00_12_339_03
│   ├── 0_00_12_347__0_00_14_156_04
│   └── 0_00_14_164__0_00_16_314_05
│     
├── E02.txt
│   ├── 0_00_16_324__0_00_17_348_06
│   ├── 0_00_17_352__0_00_21_255_07
│   ├── 0_00_21_260__0_00_23_501_08
│   ├── 0_00_23_507__0_00_25_999_09
│   └── 0_00_26_010__0_00_29_002_10
│ 
│  
├── E03.txt
│   ├── 0_00_29_013__0_00_32_176_11
│   ├── 0_00_32_182__0_00_35_982_12
│   ├── 0_00_35_993__0_00_37_245_13
│   ├── 0_00_37_253__0_00_40_177_14
│   └── 0_00_40_190__0_00_43_717_15
```

after renaming

```
Multi Folder Images
│
│
├── E01
│   ├── 0_00_01_713__0_00_05_081_01.png
│   ├── 0_00_05_093__0_00_08_916_02.png
│   ├── 0_00_08_926__0_00_12_339_03.png
│   ├── 0_00_12_347__0_00_14_156_04.png
│   └── 0_00_14_164__0_00_16_314_05.png
│     
├── E02
│   ├── 0_00_16_324__0_00_17_348_06.png
│   ├── 0_00_17_352__0_00_21_255_07.png
│   ├── 0_00_21_260__0_00_23_501_08.png
│   ├── 0_00_23_507__0_00_25_999_09.png
│   └── 0_00_26_010__0_00_29_002_10.png
│ 
│  
├── E03
│   ├── 0_00_29_013__0_00_32_176_11.png
│   ├── 0_00_32_182__0_00_35_982_12.png
│   ├── 0_00_35_993__0_00_37_245_13.png
│   ├── 0_00_37_253__0_00_40_177_14.png
│   └── 0_00_40_190__0_00_43_717_15.png
```

test after & before renaming
https://app.box.com/s/da31306nr4hizwgezi47kn6bv941i1f5

This code fulfills the task but works on one folder

```
import pathlib

IMG_DIR = pathlib.Path('.\Images\E01')

with open('E01.txt') as jabber:
    content = jabber.read().splitlines()
    director = sorted(IMG_DIR.iterdir())
    for src, dest in zip(director, content):
        src.rename(IMG_DIR / f'{dest}{src.suffix}')
```